# Enable to fetch data from lifetime value and cohorts in power bi using google analytics

Tags: powerbi

How to fetch data from lifetime value and cohorts? Please suggest any metrics or dimensions with that respect ?

I have selected the get data in power bi to fetch the data.

> DataSource.Error: Selected dimensions and metrics cannot be queried
>   together. Details:
>       DataSourceKind=GoogleAnalytics
>       DataSourcePath=GoogleAnalytics`enter code here`
>       error=[Record]

Comment: I have the same issue.  This reference was meant to help but it did not help me:https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/dimensions-metrics-explorer/